# How to consume a SOAP 1.1 web service with WCF and WSE Security?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, wsdl, wse

The application that we are currently developing requires that we consume an antiquated web service. We don't have access to the server-side code, so we are having to probe the service in an effort to discover its configuration.

We do however have access to their 'web client tool' that allows us to query the service - the only way we can get it to work this way is by ticking their box called 'WSE Security'... something that appears to be very old and (I think) no longer supported in .Net?

From what we can gather the web service appears to require a user token in a clear text format (using a combination of the WSDL's, Fiddler, Soap UI and Firebug) - not 100% certain though!

Does anyone have any ideas as to how we could consume this service within a modern application?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to configure WCF to communicate with older (usually ASMX, but some java-services too) web service that use WSE for security but it's certainly very obscure and documentation rarely exists. Rick Stahl [recently blogged about a similar situation with a web service using WSE.](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication) Although that post may not be directly applicable to your situation, you may get some benefit from seeing the steps he took to craft a compatible soap message for the older WSE service.